# Programming in matlab with logical conditions

Tags: matlab, logic, logical-operators

I have a little logical problem that I would like to have solved someday!! 
Let's say you have 4 variables, I will call them a, b, c and d. 
Now based on some logic the following conditions are given.

The program passes:

- if both a and c are filled
- if both a and d are filled
- if both b and c are filled
- if both b and d are filled
- if both c and d are filled

the program fails:

- if only a is filled
- if only b is filled
- if only c is filled
- if only d is filled
- if both a and b are filled

So if you fill in one variable you are forced to fill in more. If you don't fill in any variable no action is needed.

To keep it simple I said that 1 equals filled and 0 equals not filled. My piece of code is not working correctly because if I say that only d is filled it gives back that this is okay. But it shouldn't work since only d is a fail.

Any idea's what I could do? Maybe my way of thinking about this is not correct? Keep in mind that the 0 and 1 are just to keep this simple, so adding a sum would not help!

Here is my code:

```
a = 0; 
b = 0; 
c = 0; 
d = 1; 

if a ~=0 || b ~=0 || c ~=0 || d ~=0
    if ~(a~=0 || b~=0 && c~=0 || d~=0 ) 
       works = 1;
    else
       no = 1;
    end
end
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: `~=` what is this operator? maybe you mean `!=`?

Comment: You are so correct! I copy pasted my code to matlab and that converted it all to ~

Comment: I should correct the title as well, sorry!

Comment: “adding a sum would not help“ What does that mean? If `a`, `b` etc are logical values (true/false) then `a+b+c+d` is a quantity that tells you how many are set. That is way easier to use than the suggestion you got below.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, what I meant was that 0 and 1 are just simple representation of null or not null. But I see what you mean, the last answer I got here on this thread is going to work just fine. It is kind of like what you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is tagged MATLAB I will also give you a MATLAB solution. Basically your idea of adding a sum is just the way to go, just convert your variables to binary first, which is done with `logical`. Thus the check for fail can be done with

```
arr = logical([a,b,c,d]);
fail = sum(logical(arr))==1 || all(arr(1:2))
```

Where the first condition checks how many have been filled and the second checks whether `a` and `b` are both set.

One should note, that there are cases that satisfy both pass and fail conditions (e.g. all variables set). The solution above is fail greedy. A pass greedy solution would be (as proposed by Cris Luengo in the comments)

```
arr = logical([a,b,c,d]);
fail = sum(logical(arr))==1 || all(arr==[1,1,0,0])
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusing tags, it was Java first but it should have been Matlab. So yes thank you for a Matlab solution. These are all the conditions I was given but I would assume that all 4 variables filled in is also a pass since all conditions are met. Thank you for the simple solution, I see that I should have kept an open mind for the sum function.

Comment: What about `a`, `b` and `c` being set? My solution is greedy for fail, that is, if any of the fail conditions are met, it returns fail.

Comment: If a, b and c are set, then you meet the condition of -both a and c are filled. So that would mean you pass. The conditions only really fail if you filled in ab with nothing else. The combinations of ac, ad, bc, bd and cd are all passes, so if you have either one of these conditions its a pass. If you fill in a then the only fail you would have is ab, the rest of the combinations would lead to a pass.

Comment: So just to sum it up: it should be greedy pass?

Comment: You can do `all(arr==[1,1,0,0])` for that last case.

Comment: @NickyMattsson I think that it should be fail greedy, I was told to only take action if the conditions failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code is more readable, you can use a method to do the logic, and the easiest way to do it just translate your logic.

```
public static boolean isParamFilled(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d) {
    if ((a || b) && (c || d)) return true;
    if (c && d) return true;
    int ia = a ? 1 : 0;
    int ib = b ? 1 : 0;
    int ic = c ? 1 : 0;
    int id = d ? 1 : 0;
    // Only one of the 4 parameters is filled.
    if (ia + ib + ic + id == 1) return true;
    if (a && b) return false;
    // default value
    return false;
}

public static void main(String...args) {
    boolean a = false; 
    boolean b = false; 
    boolean c = false; 
    boolean d = true; 

    booledan worked = isParamFilled(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to program it in java as well so this answer is nice, but I somehow want something shorter? Any ideas? Thanx for this answer as well

Comment: I edit the answer, use boolean rather than int as the conditions. Please check. @Rabea

Comment: thank you. The addition of boolean is better and I will use that in my final answer.